# Majority function and Russo's Formula

Tags: probability

I am studying Boolean Functions in Garban and Steif's book (Noise sensitivity of Boolean
functions and percolation). Eercise III.5 asks us to

> Show that among all monotone Boolean functions on $\Omega_n$, $MAJ_n$ is the function with largest total influence (at $p = 1/2$).
> Hint: use the Margulis-Russo formula.

Here $MAJ_n$ is the simple majority function on $n$ variables.

I have seen proofs of this facts using Fourier analysis, but the book hasn't introducted this subjec yet. I could'nt prove this using only Russo's Formula. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By abuse of notation, let $MAJ$ denote the set of sequences who have 1 as their majority element.

Now, at $p=1/2$, you can show that if $\omega \in MAJ, \frac{dP_p(\omega)}{dp} > 0$, and conversely, if it is not in it, then the derivative will be less than $0$. (Intuitively, this is because if a sequence has more 0s than 1s, as p exceeds 1/2, it will definitely be less likely. You can also compute the derivatives or plot the functions). So, by linearity of differentiation, the best $A$ here will be $MAJ$.